# Postfix rcpt to switch

Tags: linux, email, postfix

We are looking to send emails that are going out from development box to an email address based on the from address.

If they have the following from

```
sales@domain.com
info@domain.com
support@domain.com
```

We want to switch the to address to something like

```
devgroup@domain.com
```

Comment: You're going to need a policy daemon or a milter for that, I think.

Comment: Or you could do something clever like have mail from those addresses sent to a second instance of the smtpd, which redirects everything to devgroup@ .  That's probably really complicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a map for that. ;)  (apologies to Steve Jobs and Wietse Venema for my lame humour)

Postfix is capable of address rewriting under MANY circumstances.  This circumstance would call for the use of the `smtpd_sender_restrictions` variable in *main.cf*.

Effectively, you will be putting a restriction in place to check sender addresses against an access table/db (the map!) you configure, wherein you will tell postfix to redirect to X address if the from address matches Y.

The line in *main.cf* might look like:

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions = check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/devToRewrite
```

And the contents of */etc/postfix/devToRewrite* might look like:

```
sales@domain.com REDIRECT devgroup@domain.com
```

Please keep in mind that rewriting in postfix is very delicate, and you may have configs that could potentially conflict with these intended results.

That being said, some reading to get you started:

- [Mailing list answer to someone doing something similar](http://old.nabble.com/Rewrite-recipient-dependent-on-sender-address-td21072660.html) (you're not alone!)
- [Postfix config docs for smtpd_sender_restrictions variable](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_sender_restrictions) (read carefully!)
- [Postfix SMTP relay/access control README](http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html#lists) (good to know)
- [Man page for access db definition](http://www.postfix.org/access.5.html) (don't forget `postmap -q`!!!)
- [Postfix address rewriting README](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html) (good to know)

As usual, [YMMV](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=YMMV) && [HTH](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=HTH).

:)